# Difference between app and Dyno on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I don't understand what the difference between an app and Dyno is. 
I want to use the hobby plan so that I can use an own SSL domain and that the servers stops sleeping.

I have a backend (nodeJS) and a frontend (reactJS).

Heroku says $7/Dyno. Does that mean I have to pay $7 for one app? Or do I pay $7 and can use several apps with it, so that they don't sleep?

Comment: That's two apps, two dynos; you might consider them part of a single application, but you have two separate *things* running.

Comment: So does one app always run only in one dyno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An App is a set of one or more different dynos. This latter can be either of the same or different type (e.g. web, workers, ...) and having a different tier (e.g. standard, hobby, performance ...). You can see [here](https://www.heroku.com/dynos) the details for your better understanding. 
It is possible to execute more instances of the same dyno type (e.g. for high-availability, processing concurrency ...). You can see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#dyno-formation) for details.
You basically pay for the number of dynos you run.

Comment: So that means, one app has at least one dyno and if I want this app to never sleep I need to pay at least $7 for one app? But if I want to expand my app and add more dynos to the app because of availability reasons or concurrency I have to pay for each dyno, which I add to the app?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You pay for the number of running dynos. You are charged per second of activity of each dyno, so you can also dynamically change the number of dynos (e.g. from zero to 5) depending on the App load you expect.

Comment: When I add 5 dynos (web=5) to my nodeJS backend, does that mean it runs 5 instances of it parallel? So when there are incoming requests, how will it be decided which instance will be used? Is there some load balancing between the dynos from Heroku?

Comment: When you increase the number of dynos (scale) they run in parallel. Incoming requests are dispatched by the Heroku routing mechanism to the available dynos. The selection of a dyno is basically random. You can find details here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing